# Error in Central Administration: Ribbon <Tab> node must have a <Scaling> subnode.

Tags: ribbon, administration

We have SharePoint 2013 (MOSS), in Central Administration I navigate to Application Management -> Manage service applications. When I click on the Secure Store Service (or when I select the Secure Store Service and select Manage) I got the error message:

Ribbon  node must have a  subnode.

I'm unaware of any customisations that have been applied within Central Administration so I don't understand why this error message is occurring within Central Admin. The Secure Store Service has been started.

This problem occurs in Google Chrom and IE11.

Can anybody help?

Regards,

Ben

Comment: For completeness: Does it happen in Firefox?

Comment: Yes it happens in Firefox too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this after contacting Microsoft. The problem was that the SSSvc site feature wasn't activated on the Central Admin site, which can only be enabled using PowerShell:

Enable-SPFeature -identity " SSSvcAdmin " -URL http://centraladminURL